# How can I use GroupBy with a list of objects and return IList<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, group-by

I have a method that, must return a list of objects, but i don't know how!
my problem is converting(or maybe casting)groupdResult to IList.

```
internal IList<MyClass> MyMethod()
{
   IList<MyClass> result=new List<MyClass>();
  
   IList<MyClass> rawData = this.GetRawDatas();

   foreach (MyClass item in rawDatas){
        // do somthings
        MyClass balancedData = new MyClass();  
        if(some conditions){
           result.Add(balancedData);
        }
   }
   var groupdResult = result.GroupBy(x => x.MyField).ToList();
   return groupdResult;
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with your code...its returning result as List<IEnumerable> type...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
var groupdResult = result.GroupBy(x => x.MyField).ToList();
```

to

```
var groupdResult = result.GroupBy(x => x.MyField).SelectMany(g=>g.ToList).ToList();
```

Solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Think about it: The result is either going to be a list of groups or a list of *ungrouped* objects. I believe that what you want is actually just a sorted list:

```
return result.OrderBy(x => x.MyField).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the List/IList you're having trouble with.  It's the fact that GroupBy does not return MyClass.

GroupBy returns an IGrouping, so the line

```
var groupdResult = result.GroupBy(x => x.MyField).ToList();
```

returns a List< IGrouping< MyClass > >.